# How to check if string only contains alphabets in F#

Tags: f#

I have a string which should only contain alphabets. To check that I have written the following code

```
let isCorrectString(str:string) = 
 let isInRange x = (x > 64 && x < 91 ) || (x > 96 && x < 123) || x = 32
 not (str.Any(fun ch -> not (isInRange (ch :?> int)) ))
```

I am obviously using LINQ's `Any' extension method here. Is there any better way to write the above code ?

Comment: does it need to contain complete alphabets or can it have partial alphabets in it?

Comment: Your function returns the valid characters and not a boolean. Is that what you want?

Comment: @SamIam It can have repeating alphabets but it can't have anything other than alphabets. examples "this is a correct string" , "this is ALSO a correct string", "but this is not,", "so is'nt this one"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to just verify that it's correct, you could do:

```
let isCorrectString(str:string) = 
    let isInRange x = (x > 64 && x < 91 ) || (x > 96 && x < 123) || x = 32
    let bad = 
        str
        |> Seq.map (fun c -> isInRange(int c))
        |> Seq.exists (fun b -> b = false)
    not bad
```

Note that this may be a simpler alternative:

```
let isCorrectString(str:string) = 
    str
    |> Seq.forall (fun c -> System.Char.IsLetter(c) || c = ' ')
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
let isCorrectString(str:string) = 
    str
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun c -> not(System.Char.IsLetter(c) || c = ' '))
    |> Option.isNone
```

Comment: Cool, I would rather call it 'bad' than 'good', that would give correct meaning to it.

Comment: @fahadash Yeah - edited already, + showed simpler alternative

Comment: @fahadash BTW -Did another edit with a version that is easier to read, IMO

Comment: `Seq.exists` with a double negation is `Seq.forall`, isn't it? Thus `let isCorrectString : string -> bool = Seq.forall (fun c -> System.Char.IsLetter c || System.Char.IsWhiteSpace c)` or something.

Comment: @kaefer Yes, of course - that's easier to read, too - edited.

Comment: There's also `String.forall`, which you could partially apply to get `let isCorrectString = String.forall (fun c -> System.Char.IsLetter(c) || c = ' ')`

Comment: `String.forall` is significantly faster for per-character string processing than `Seq.forall`, especially if the strings are relatively small.

Comment: Also worth calling out that `Char.IsLetter` is __NOT__ the same as checking for `a-z + A-Z`.  `IsLetter` [matches a wide range of non-English characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx) (e.g. `'ǅ'`, `'ʰ'`, `'ˁ'`). Due to this, it is rather slower than manually checking `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')`.